# How to check .xls file size before uploading in ASP.NET 4?

Tags: asp.net, file-upload, asp.net-4.0, filesize

Following is a part of my ASP.NET code:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fuUploader" runat="server" />
<br />
<asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" onclick="btnSubmit_Click" />
```

Is it possible to check file size (to be less than 4mb) before uploading to the server?

My primary browser is IE9, but it would be better also to work in last versions of Firefox and Chrome. Usage of HTML 5 is preferred if it can somehow help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mostly for now you can't do this without

1. Using something like flash/java (just google for them, there are lots of components available)
2. Using HTML5/Javascript file APIs (like Blob API). Currently they aren't implemented in IE9 AFAIK.

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look at the NeatUpload solution
http://neatupload.codeplex.com/

They have an option to limit the file size. I'm not sure if they check that **before** uploading but it is a very good control anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
   protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(fuUploader.PostedFile.ContentLength>4000000) //if more than 4MB
            //do what would you like
    }
```

Comment: That wont work - it performs the check after the file has already been uploaded.

Comment: There are a lot of methods to check file size after uploading, but I need check it before. Every code sample written in C# is already mean what it will be executed at server.

Comment: You can't check it before uploading. File must be uploaded to server check its size.

Comment: @erdincozdemir - if it is impossible, how can many of websites show a "smart" file upload, i mean a progress bar, indicating the file upload status? For example, try to upload a file using Google Docs.

Comment: @Dehumanizer look at PiRX's answer above. It's the answer for your question.